# what's the big deal with "amor fati"?

Tags: nietzsche, determinism

Why do I keep hearing about  Nietzche's "amor fati" (meaning "love your fate") or "eternal recurrence" ? It seems to boil down to  "one should strive to be willing to relive eternally one's life" which is a fancy way of saying we shouldnt have any regret.

Once you accept that the "you" of now is not the same as the you of "back then" then it follows that the wrong choices you made back then were because you had less information. Furthermore, it is not the "you" of now that is supposed to relive your life, but the infinite number of yourselves at each moment of the past.

So all you need to get rid of regret is to accept determinism, which is the same as fate, so "amor fati" ="love your fate"  = "love determinism". However, if you should not regret your fate/determinism, then you shouldnt "love your fate/determinism" either. This is all moot, fate is you, you are fate. A rock doesnt have to love being a rock, a cat doesnt have to  love being a cat, and you dont have to love being yourself.

So, did I  miss something about "amor fati" ?

Answer (score 1):

Nietzsche was initially a follower of Schopenhauer who had a very dour view of life.  Pessimistic religions view life on earth as 'fallen', and Schopenhauer took this kind of view, with the only salvation being (faith in) the denial/suppression of will.

> Individuality inheres indeed primarily in the intellect; ... But it
> inheres also in the will, inasmuch as the character is individual: yet
> the character itself is abolished in the denial of the will. ... true
> salvation lies in its *denial* - [Schopenhauer, WWV2, pp, 428,
> 430](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/40868/40868-h/40868-h.html#Pg428)

Nietzsche took Schopenhauer's Pessimism (that life is a vale of tears) and a nascent nihilism of the time, and produced his Nihilism, (which in turn compels the revaluation of all values).  As you can see, he had rather changed his mind about Schopenhauer by this time.

> The unhealthiest kind of man all over Europe (in all classes) is the
> soil out of which Nihilism grows: this species of man will regard
> eternal recurrence as damnation ...  - [Nietzsche, WTP pg. 53](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/52914/52914-h/52914-h.htm#Page_52)

The follow-through from Nihilism, the revaluation of all values, puts the emphasis back on the will, working in cycles of mastery, on various levels of analogy.

> Since will is the overpowering of itself, no richness [*Reichtum*] of
> life  will satisfy it. It has its power in overreaching [*im
> Überreichen*] - namely, in  reaching over its own will. Thus it, as
> the same, is constantly coming back unto itself as the Same. - [Heidegger, Off the Beaten Track, p. 177](https://archive.org/stream/ApolloHumanRightsBooks/26585615-Heidegger-Martin-Off-the-Beaten-Track_djvu.txt)

This positive cycle of mastery is what Nietzsche calls *amor fati*, in contrast with Schopenhauer's Pessimism and quietism, which he had turned against.

***Addendum***

Heidegger adds somewhat to Nietzsche's analysis.

> Nietzsche's thought that thinks the overman originates from a thinking
> that thinks being ontologically as beings and so submits to the
> essence of  metaphysics without, however, being able to experience
> this essence within  metaphysics. That is why, for Nietzsche just as
> in all metaphysics before  him, it remains hidden in what way the
> essence of man is determined on  the basis of the essence of being.
> That is why, in Nietzsche's metaphysics,  the ground of the essential
> connection between the will to power and the  overman is necessarily
> obscured. Yet in every obscuration an appearing is  already prevailing
> at the same time. The *existentia* that is part of the *essentia* of
> beings, i.e., of the will to power, is the eternal return of the same. - [Heidegger, Off the Beaten Track, p. 188](https://archive.org/stream/ApolloHumanRightsBooks/26585615-Heidegger-Martin-Off-the-Beaten-Track_djvu.txt)

And so.

> That *everything recurs*, is the very nearest *approach of a world of
> Becoming to a world of Being* - [Nietzsche, WTP
> 617](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/52915/52915-h/52915-h.htm#Page_107)

Comment: A niggling point... Nietzsche was not a nihilist. As your second quote implies, Nietzsche thought nihilism grew where people cynically espoused traditional received authority. If he wanted us to break through moral doctrine, it was only because he thought moral doctrine was stale hypocrisy used for social control, and no one could achieve *true* moral understanding without first disposing of corrupt tenets. A lot of people have used N's work to establish their own cult followings (which is where the idea that N was a nihilist comes from), but we should be clear on the issue.

Comment: Hmm, the [WTP Preface 3](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/52914/52914-h/52914-h.htm#Page_1) suggests Nietzsche *used* Nihilism (capital N) to move onto the revaluation, e.g. "the present writer [Nietzsche] has done little else, hitherto, than *reflect and meditate*, ... like a prophetic bird-spirit that looks backwards when it would announce what is to come; like the first perfect European Nihilist, who, however, has already outlived Nihilism in his own soul - who has out-grown, overcome, and dismissed it."

Comment: But the operative phrase in that quote is the last one: "who has out-grown, overcome, and dismissed it". In N's mind nihilism is (for lack of a better term) a 'fact' about the world. But it's a 'fact' we can overcome.

Comment: The impression I get is that once the "hitherto highest values" had devalued themselves and vanished like morning mist, then Nihilism would disappear too, like an illusion, having served its purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Has N's amor fati, anything to do with fate, love or love of fate ?

Comment: See page 149 of Daniel Ferrer's paper here: https://philpapers.org/rec/FERGPK

Comment: read it.....it's blurry...always subject to a nebula of interpretations, that's his style I guess